# Publishing from Workstation but can't echo from turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After following the Turtlebot networking setup and verifying that both the workstation and the turtlebot laptop are connected via `rostopic list` I've run into a problem:
On the workstation I run:
`rostopic pub -r10 /hello std_msgs/String "hello"`
On the turtlebot laptop I run:
`rostopic echo /hello`

However, nothing prints on the turtlebot laptop. What's even more baffling is that when I run `rostopic list` on turtlebot I can see `/hello` listed.

Any help is much appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33167/publishing-from-workstation-but-can%27t-echo-from-turtlebot/) by [njavia66](https://answers.ros.org/users/1906/njavia66/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please review the [Network Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) wiki page.  It sounds like you have not set your ROS_HOSTNAME on the workstation correctly to allow the robot to be able to reach the workstation.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0